# In VS code when I try to open the live server; then page show "CANNOT GET .....". How can I solve this problem?

Tags: web, browser, vscode-extensions, liveserver

In VS code IDE I create an html file. I tried to open it in the live server but it shows an error.
The page shows "CANNOT GET ...link..." but it doesn't load.
I tried to find problem-fixing tutorials on youtube and other sources. But can't get any permanent help.

Screenshot of the problem I'm facing,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcMVf.png)

Provide me with any permanent solution about this solution.
If you recommend me any substitute I will try it.